PCB Design Review Request - Boost Converter Breakout Board
I recently decided I wanted to design a breakout board for the MIC2253-06YML-TR (datasheet), though an evaluation board exists for it I will need this chip for an ongoing project I will be working on and figured it would be good practice to make a layout that involves switching converters.
The premise is a two-layered board with the bottom copper as GND and the top acting as copper pours for VIN, VOUT, FB, and the Inductor. I wanted to have the ability to switch between an analog and digital potentiometer, so I added some jumpers where power can be applied and the user can switch between the two different types. I have never used a digital potentiometer before, so I figured this would be a good first step in using them. The digital pot is the MCP4541-104E/MS (datasheet) which is a non-volatile pot, as I want the value stored in the pot even after power is removed from the converter.
I followed the user guide to the best of my ability, except for excluding the OVP resistors, as I couldn't find a way of squeezing them in the layout without routing underneath the inductor.
Here is the schematic:

Followed by the PCB layout:


Some concerns I have:

The feedback (FB) pin copper pour is rather long, something like this would induce a lot of noise.

The overall layout and the inductor switching nodes seem fine, but the output loop to the two potentiometers and VOUT are rather long.

The high voltage command/address 0 pin on the digital pot. I have this tied to a 2 mm pad, so I can jump a wire to my MCU if needed, but I am unsure how to incorporate this pin. I see from the datasheet that it is the starting address, but — in general — using this with an STM32 can be a little confusing since I have never done this before.

Does the digital pot need pull-up resistors? It's not mentioned in the datasheet or the application example, but I know that typically 10ks are needed on the SCL and SDA lines.

Is there a problem with incorporating jumpers for switching the feedback type? Again, I know switching converters can be very noisy, so I tried my best to compensate for that while also providing clearance between the analog and digital pot.



Is there a reason that you didn't route the exposed GND pad out to a large GND pour on the top, like the user guide suggests? I think you're likely going to have some thermal issues with the layout how it is currently.

I mainly did this due to lack of a gap or space to fit a GND copper pour considering the FB and switching nodes, though I will try and see if I can incorporate this.

I reviewed the schematic, and noted a few things (not major things, but still some feedback)

Consider having a 0 ohm resistor between your EN & VIN signal. Without this you have no way of setting EN low, which might be desirable in some situations. Having a 0 ohm resistor there at least gives you the option of using the EN signal at some point if you want to.

You seem to have resistor values that are not from the E12/E24 series, nor from a higher series (such as 48.1k, 46.4k). You might have issues sourcing resistor values from outside the regular series of values, consider changing those resistor values.

Test points on I2C signals is a good idea, however always be careful when placing test points on communication lines if they are high speed communication lines (which I2C is not, so you'll be fine). If the test points are large or far away from the signal traces, they can have an impact on signal integrity.

You seem to have no ESD protection in your design. I would strongly advice to add ESD protection, such as TVS diodes on off-board signals, and perhaps also series resistors to your I2C lines.

Off-board I2C signals are usually a recipe for issues, I2C is very susceptible to noise, especially since you don't have any filtering on those signals. Consider using a differential serial communication instead, like RS-485.

Have you checked the resistor accuracy of the Digipot? They usually have very wide tolerance specs, yours has a resistance accuracy of +/- 20%, is that good enough for your application?

Your schematic doesn't show the voltage rating of your capacitors, but as usual I would recommend double checking that you haven't selected a too low voltage rating on your capacitors. Would also recommend double checking current requirements for inductor and schottky diode.


Your layout looks good enough I'd say, but I'd check the distance to the board edge for connector J7 and the trace below, I can't see the distance there but make sure you're not violating the edge clearance rule of whatever manufacturer you use. Also, I can't see where you have the GND via for capacitor C7, I'm guessing it might be in the pad of the capacitor, or below it? That usually works out fine, but it's normally recommended to avoid via-in-pad if possible due to possible manufacturing issues.

Thank you for the feedback, I will be adding ESD protection along with the EN resistor, C7 the vias are placed in-between the two pads of the cap and the analog pot doesn't need to be too accurate as this is just a test board.
What resources do you recommend for using RS-485 with a digital pot? Everything I found online seems to use I2C or SPI.

If you want to use an I2C-component with the I2C communication going off the board I would recommend using an I2C-to-serial converter, or an I2C repeater, something like the P82B96 or the PCA9615.

I see, so I'm assuming this IC would have to be placed on the PCB, or can I have it connected externally via a breadboard? I'm a bit short on space right now unless I move the Vout copper pour further to make room for it.

Both of those components convert I2C (which is a single-ended communication protocol, and therefore quite noise-sensitive) to a differential (i.e., dual-ended) protocol, which is much more resistant to noise. You'll probably want to have one converter in each end of your signal chain, to convert from I2C to differential and then back to I2C at the end of the signal chain.

The digital pot idea is going to give you potential problems. The maximum voltage you can have on the A, B or W pins is: -
Voltage on PxA, PxW, and PxB with respect to VSS ......-0.3V to VDD + 0.3V

So, if the boost output is high, you might have exceeded the ratings for the chip.

The rating would be exceeded, would connecting a DAC to the output of the digital pot and then tying the DAC to the converter be a possible solution?

@dreece2498 I cannot envisage what you are suggesting. Try starting a new post based on this comment and show some kind of image of what you suggest.

@dreece2498 if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
