Adjusting Output Voltage Via A Digital Pot?
I recently designed a boost converter breakout board (original post here link that was going to be controlled via an analog or digital potentiometer, schematic can be seen here:

Along with the layout:

However, I made a design oversight with the digital pot as the pins 5,6, and 7 on the digital pot can only withstand a range of -0.3V to 0.3V. My boost converter I want to output up to 30V and will exceed this threshold because of my output voltage.
Would I be better off just controlling the boost converter via pwm, or perhaps a DAC?
The main issue I see right now with any of the 3 methods (DAC, Digital Pot, PWM) seen here: Link is the voltage rating of the pin after the feedback network being exceeded even after the voltage divider.
I want the converter to be fairly accurate, at least for the digital control within a %10 margin of error. The only solution I can come up with right now is to use an opto-isolator, with the input tied to the digital pot and the output tied to the FB voltage divider as opto-isolators can withstand higher voltages than the pins on the digital pot.

Friendly note: This question would be a lot easier to help with if you added in your requirements + relevant links, or at least linked to your previous question with those resources: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/725063/pcb-design-review-request-boost-converter-breakout-board :)

That particular digital pot can withstand a voltage of GND to Vcc (and a few hundred mV more).
The feedback voltage of the SMPS chip is 1.245V nominally. So if you connect the pot as a rheostat with a series resistor you can make a voltage divider:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
That will allow you to set the voltage from 4V to more than 30V.
However the relationship of pot setting to voltage is nonlinear and your pot has only about 128 steps, so the resolution will be about 2V per step at the high end and more like 20mV at the low end.
That will get quite a bit better if you don't demand such a large ratio of minimum to maximum voltage. With 10V in your minimum output voltage is around 10V anyway.

Given the clarified and much reduced range, 20 to 30V, you can implement the above circuit with a 10kΩ digital pot, and 249kΩ and 10kΩ resistors. That will give you a range from 16.7 to 32V nominally, with maximum step size of less than 0.25V.

I think even with the resistor divider I have set right now it still exceeds the voltage due to the high output. TH reason I have such a large ratio is because I want to power the circuit via a lithium ion battery, would adding in another converter prior to this to step up the voltage be a viable solution.

What is your desired range of output voltage and the actual range of input voltage?

Desired range is 20-30V, actual input voltage range is from 3.7V to 4.2V

I misunderstood your original question, I'd want a voltage range of 0 to 30V ideally, though a range of 0 to 20V would work as I was trying to create a power supply.
